# ¿Hay alguna palabra similar a "vistazo" pero para escuchar algo?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Ayer tuve una conversación parecida a esta:

> — A mí me gustan Tal Grupo y TalOtro.
>   — Ah, pues deberías escuchar a GrupoNuevo, están muy bien.
>   — Genial, mañana les echaré un ...

Y aquí es donde me surgió la duda. Pues lo que quería decir, es que pretendía escuchar rápidamente y por encima algunas de sus canciones, para hacerme una idea del estilo. Es decir, algo equivalente a **echar un vistazo**:

> **[vistazo](http://dle.rae.es/?w=vistazo)**.
>
> 1. m. Mirada superficial o ligera.

Pero para escuchar, no para mirar.

¿Existe alguna palabra con este significado?

Comment: Cuando tengas tiempo, dale una escuchadita a esta canción.

Comment: @David - Si pusieras esta aportación en una respuesta, yo la apoyaría.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Por el diccionario, sabemos que la diferencia entre *oír* y *escuchar* es, precisamente, que el segundo verbo implica el primero pero prestando atención:

> **[oír](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QxCw3RS)**
>
> 1. tr. Percibir con el oído los sonidos.
>
> **[escuchar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GLkff9P)**
>
> 1. tr. Prestar atención a lo que se oye.

Por tanto, usando el verbo *oír* ya estamos implicando que no se está prestando atención, sino que simplemente notas cómo el sonido llega a tus oídos. Y el verbo oír tiene un sustantivo que indica su acción y efecto:

> **[oída](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QwzwsIK)**
>
> 1. f. Acción y efecto de oír.

De aquí viene, por ejemplo, la expresión "saber algo de oídas", que es "enterarte de algo por medio de otros, sin haberlo escuchado personalmente". Luego yo te propongo la expresión:

> **darle/echarle una oída**

Que vendría a decir que los vas a oír (vas a dejar que el sonido llegue a tus oídos), pero no los vas a escuchar (no les vas a prestar atención).

Ejemplos del CREA que usan esta expresión (negritas mías):

> *Tan sólo por eso ya vale la pena **darle una oída** a un álbum que ciertamente es más de lo que aparenta.*
>
> Revista Hoy, 23-29/12/1996, "QUARTET: Pat Metheny Group" (Chile).
>
> ---
>
> *Bastará ver una fotografía de Marylin Manson, un video de White Zombie o **darle una oída** a Nine Inch Nails, para comprobar que detrás de ese aterrador desfile de máscaras existe algo que se ha transformado en un común denominador del rock de hoy.*
>
> Clarín, 03/02/1997, "LAS NUEVAS BANDAS METÁLICAS RECURREN AL HORROR PARA SACUDIR A SUS FANS" (Argentina).

Comment: Acá también decimos *pegarle una oída*, y se entiende también perfectamente si se dice *pegarle una escuchada* (aunque ésta última sea un poco más rara).

Comment: @pablodf76 - Me gustaría ver *una escuchada* en una respuesta.

Answer (score 6):

Estas son un poco diferentes, pero dado el caso pueden servirte:

> Prestar oreja
>
> Parar la oreja
>
> Poner oreja
>
> Dar oreja

Significan (al menos en América del Sur) "poner atención".

Aunque no responden exactamente a tu pregunta, me parece que la oración que pones de ejemplo es equivalente a:

> ¡Genial, mañana les pongo oreja!