# Echar/dar/pegar una *-ada/-ída

Tags: verbos, modismos, expresiones

Esta pregunta viene a cuento de esta otra, 
[¿Hay alguna palabra similar a "vistazo" pero para escuchar algo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22541),
a partir de la cual me doy cuenta de la variedad de expresiones que pueden usarse con este particular formato, que es algo así como

> *dar|echar un(a)* raíz verbal + *-azo|ada|ída*

Por ejemplo, *dar un vistazo*, *echar una oída*, etc. En inglés este tipo de expresiones utilizan casi siempre *to have* o *to take* (*take a peek*, *have a look*, etc.). En castellano, según me parece, la variedad de verbos utilizados como base es mayor.

Supongo que podría transformarse en una entrada de wiki eventualmente. La pregunta es: **¿qué expresiones como éstas existen en los distintos dialectos castellanos, y en particular, qué verbos pueden usarse?**

En rioplatense:

- *echar una mirada*
- *pegar una revisada*
- *dar una hojeada*
- *mandar una leída*

Los derivados verbales no tienen que ser necesariamente de este tipo: cualquier sustantivo deverbal funciona, incluso con derivación cero (como *baño* o *paseo*), pero me interesan más los derivados como los citados, que parecen ser los más productivos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### echar un...

- echar una bocanada, [h]ojeada, meada, mirada, partida
- echar un bocado, clavado
- echar un fonazo, hechizo, lazo, vistazo

#### dar un...

- dar un aprobado, lavado
- dar un abrazo, frenazo, jicarazo, pelotazo, portazo, porrazo, puñetazo, vistazo
- dar una enseñanza, golpiza, paliza
- dar una bofetada, mirada, nalgada, [h]ojeada, patada, palmada [en...]