# The use of 'que' when saying 'no solo A sino también B'

Tags: gramática, vocabulario

I'm not very fluent in Spanish so I have a question,,,TT

Is the sentence 'No solo no puedo ver esto sino que también no puedo escuchar esto' correct?
(I intended to mean 'Not only I can't see this but also I can't hear this.')

I am confused because in school I learned that I only have to use 'que' when the sentences are compared in the structure of 'no solo A sino también B'.

Should I use 'que' only when the verbs are different, or should I use them also when the verb is same but it is in the form of sentence?

I have no idea,,, I don't get it,,, Ayuda por favor TT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you learned (*no sólo A sino también B*) is fine, but in this case, when *B* is not a noun phrase but a complete proposition (a subsentence with its own verb), then it requires *que* before it ([DPD, *sino*, 2.1](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=NVSKIU2kQD6AqlzZd7)). If *B* were a noun, you wouldn't need *que*.

This is what you learned:

> *no sólo [(pasa) algo]<sub>A</sub> sino también [otra cosa]<sub>B</sub>*

Note that *A* can be a noun phrase alone (*algo* = "something") or it can have a verb (*pasa algo* = "something happens"). It doesn't matter; the structure works the same for the first part.

But when the second part *B* is a full proposition (a subordinate sentence with a verb), you have to add *que*:

> *no sólo [(pasa) algo]<sub>A</sub> sino **que** también [pasa otra cosa]<sub>B</sub>*

Also, see that *también no* is wrong; in Spanish *también* + a negative is rendered as *tampoco*:

> *No sólo no puedo ver esto sino que tampoco puedo escuchar esto.*

The natural thing to do in a sentence like this, where the object of the two verbs in the two parts of the sentence is the same, is to replace the latter instance with a shorter [clitic pronoun](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/clitics.htm):

> *No sólo no puedo ver **esto** sino que tampoco puedo escuchar**lo**.*

Finally, in this case you could shorten the sentence even more and get rid of the *que* by making both parts of the sentence subordinate to the verb *puedo*:

> *No sólo no puedo ver esto sino tampoco escucharlo.*

This works, I think, because *A* = *ver esto* and *B* = *escucharlo*; they both function as noun phrases and the main verb stays outside. (If this is too complex for you, forget it for now; just remember the general rules stated above.)

Comment: thanks for your help!! I don't understand it perfectly but I get the feeling of how I should use this phrase,,, Gracias :)

Comment: I know this is not the point in this question, but I think that, at least in Spain, **oírlo** would be preferred to **escucharlo.**

Comment: @Patricio You're right. I just searched and found a question and an [answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25632/14627) of mine regarding that. I didn't think of it because for me *escuchar* is natural in that position.